# FullCalendar Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in Spring MVC. I have a controller listAll(). This controller return all events, but I don´t know how I can use this controller function in JavaScript.

home.html

```
$(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            events: [

                {
                  title  : 'tarea2',
                  start  : '2018-12-24',
                  end    : '2010-12-25'
                }

              ]
        })
    });
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView getPlanificado() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("events", eventsService.listAll());
    model.setViewName("/entrenador/home");
    return model;

}
```

I need to use the list of events from controller MVC  (events) to JavaScript, but I don´t know how include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to make an AJAX call and return JSON response instead of model.

Create a pojo class which consists all the fields for an event to map JSON like below.

```
public class Event{
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
    //getters setters and other required fields
}
```

Then controller method like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getPlanificado()
{
    List<Event> events = eventsService.listAll();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    if (calendarEvents.size() > 0)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().include("id","title","end","start").exclude("*").serialize(calendarEvents), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(null, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Then  call the above method like below AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    headers:{
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(result){
        if(result!== null){
            var len = result.length;
            if(len > 0){
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log(jsonString);
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    console.log(result[i]);
                    var title=result[i].title;
                    var start=result[i].start;
                    var startDate = new Date(start);
                    console.log("startDate :"+startDate);
                    var end=result[i].end;
                    var endDate = new Date(end);
                    console.log("endDate :"+endDate);
                    var event={ title:classname, start:startDate, end:endDate};
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true);

                }
            } 
        }else{
            console.log("NO events");
        }
    },error: function (result) {
            console.log("AJAX error");
    }
});
```

NOTE : I used [flexjson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.flexjson/flexjson/2.0) to convert java object to json serialization purpose.